# Plot Azmuth Angle In Basemap

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I'm wondering if there is a way to plot azimuth angles projections from an off surface object (ie. a satellite) in python. I'm currently using Basemap, is there some method or maybe another library I should be using?

Comment: What do you mean by "azimuth angles projections?" Is [this](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geos.html) what you're looking for? (note that the `lat_0` keyword argument can be included to move the center of the plot off the equator)

Comment: Or maybe [this](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/nsper.html)?

Comment: So azmuth being this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth, I'd like to make a plot of the projection of from a floating observer off earth onto earth from a reference point and given a reference point that connects the observer and the earth's surface.

Comment: I think I understand. How to do that in Basemap isn't immediately obvious to me, but I wouldn't be surprised if a more advanced user could do/has done it.

Comment: I thought about this some more. You'd have to use some sort of projection mathematics from the object relative to earth. This I think would be an awesome feature to have...maybe a nice addon.